How can I use fast Fourier transform to divide into low and high frequency components?
I have this data (where x is time (seconds) and y is diopters (D)):
j={{0.,-0.0404514},{0.1,0.149749},{0.2,0.198019},{0.3,0.233192},{0.4,0.579682},{0.5,0.806873}, {0.6, 0.663778},{0.7,0.696021},{0.8,0.79514},{0.9,0.738305},{1.,0.764991},{1.1,0.873105}, {1.2, 0.92797},{1.3,0.966118},{1.4,0.996534},{1.5,0.790578},{1.6,1.00572},{1.7,0.995352},{1.8,1.01874},{1.9,0.729424},{2.,0.606878},{2.1,0.536286},{2.2,0.737062},{2.3,0.745238},{2.4,0.831278},{2.5,0.661876},{2.6,0.727583},{2.7,0.966425},{2.8,0.885887},{2.9,0.764993},{3.,0.760021},{3.1,0.799975},{3.2,0.833339},{3.3,0.95302},{3.4,0.720215},{3.5,0.77478},{3.6,1.05699}}

How can I use fast fourier transform to divide into low (between 0 and 0.9 Hz) and high (between 1 and 2.1 Hz) frequency components and found mean power (D^2/Hz)?
Thank you so much.

You only have 37 points in your data. To get the mean power you need to average over many more points. Do you have more data?

Not only more data are needed, but also better time resolution

related

related

It's a signal processing problem, nearly unsolvable in your case. Don't expect Mathematica to do the expertise. "Fast Fourier" is a standard approach that people mainly choose only by ... mimetism.

You do not need to "roll your own". MMA has the tools for this. You may use "LowpassFilter" and "HighpassFilter".
However, considering your data, a switching frequency of 1Hz seems way to low. This is obvious from:
freq = 1;
ListLinePlot[{j[[All, 2]], HighpassFilter[ys, freq, SampleRate -> 10],
   LowpassFilter[ys, freq, SampleRate -> 10]}]


A frequency of 2 seems more appropriate:
freq = 2;
ListLinePlot[{j[[All, 2]], HighpassFilter[ys, freq, SampleRate -> 10],
   LowpassFilter[ys, freq, SampleRate -> 10]}]


